# spring-boot 2.5.2 with mapstruct\lombok and swagger2 (mapstruct not work)

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-2.0, mapstruct

I upgrade the project framework of spring-boot from [2.1.0.RELEASE] to [2.5.2] and some dependencies,but now the swagger2 and mapstruct can't work together.i use lombok too.here is my pom.xml (remove some irrelevant stuff),but now i get blow error:

```
java: package org.mapstruct does not exist
```

pom.xml

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jedis.version>2.9.0</jedis.version>
    <log4jdbc.version>1.16</log4jdbc.version>
    <swagger.version>2.9.2</swagger.version>
    <fastjson.version>1.2.54</fastjson.version>
    <druid.version>1.1.10</druid.version>
    <commons-pool2.version>2.5.0</commons-pool2.version>
    <org.mapstruct.version>1.4.2.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    <org.projectlombok.version>1.18.20</org.projectlombok.version>
    <lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>0.2.0</lombok-mapstruct-binding.version>
</properties>
<!--Spring boot start-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-properties-migrator</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>

    <!-- spring cache -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- redis -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!--Spring boot end-->


    <!--swagger2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
        <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
        <version>${swagger.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
        <artifactId>swagger-models</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.21</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--lombok and mapstruct -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>



<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <target>1.8</target> <!-- depending on your project -->
                <annotationProcessorPaths>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.projectlombok.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                        <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <path>
                        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                        <artifactId>lombok-mapstruct-binding</artifactId>
                        <version>${lombok-mapstruct-binding.version}</version>
                    </path>
                    <!-- other annotation processors -->
                </annotationProcessorPaths>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

if i remove

```
<exclusion>
   <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
   <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
</exclusion>
```

from swagger2, then i get this error.

```
java: Couldn't retrieve @Mapper annotation
```

so, how should i do in this situation,thanks.
BTW，im using Intellij IDEA 2021.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my bad, i did't notice the

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
    <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
    <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

change to

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
          <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId>
          <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

is worked.